# Why does error occur at var obj={'A':'B','C':obj['A']};?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to create an javascript object, which value of "C" copies value of "A" :

```js
var obj={
  'A':'some complex function returns a string',
  'C':obj['A']
};
```

But it has errors. I try to check if key 'A' really created:

```js
var f=function(str){
  console.log(str);
  return str;
};
var obj={
  [f('A')]:[f('B')],
  "C":obj['A']
};
```

which prints

```
B
A
```

and then errors. Which means 'A' created but it still says obj['A'] is not defined. Why would that happen?

Comment: `obj` wasn't defined yet when this object literal was being evaluated.

Comment: the error clearly explains the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt obviously fails because by the time the code constructs new object the value of `obj` variable was not assigned yet.

You could check it by using

```
var obj = { C: typeof obj}
```

> I want to create an javascript object, which value of "C" copies value of "A"

If you want `C` to always reflect the value of `A` you could use

```
var obj = {
  A: 'Some value',
  get C() {
    return this.A;
  }
}
```

Or split `obj` declaration

```
var obj = { A: 'Some Value' };
obj.C = obj.A
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because `obj` was not yet defined when you attempted to acces it from inside of it.

To make your code work you could use a getter.

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be
>   called when that property is looked up. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Also you do not need quotes for your object properties.

> Quotes can be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal
>   or a valid identifier name.

```js
var obj = {
  A : 'Hello',
  get C() {
    return this.A;
  }
};

console.log(obj.C);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference a variable that has not created yet. You can do it like this.

```
var obj = { 'A' : 'some complex function returns a string' }
obj['C'] = obj['A']
```